# 2 mysql tables mapped as 1 extending entity

Tags: inheritance, orm, doctrine, mapping

I have the following setup:

- A doctrine Entity Client mapped to my clients table
- A doctrine Entity CampaignClient mapped to my campaign_clients table

In the database, the campaign_clients.client_id represents a foreign key to clients.id. In Doctrine you would usually make a relationship between those 2 objects.

However, I got pointed out that Doctrine2 offers the ability to have a nice OO structure for this: `class CampaignClient extends Client`. This way (according to the theory) I can retrieve the CampaignClient and have all the client fields available without having to use `$campaign_client->getClient();` to get myself the Client object.

So my question is, what is it called? I have searched on google on a lot of terms but I just don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find something after more searching in the documentation. What I need is Class Table Inheritance: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance